# How can I select the element prior to a last child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking for a CSS selector that lets me select the penultimate child of  a list.

```
<ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li> <!-- select the pre last item dynamically no matter how long this list is -->
     <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

**Static method:**

```
ul li:nth-child(5)
```

**Dynamic method:**

```
ul li:last-child(-1)
```

which of course doesn't validate, also nth-last-child doesn't seem to provide a dynamic way.. I can fallback to javascript but I'm wondering if there is a css way I overlooked

Comment: It's usually called "second last". There's also another fancy word for it: "penultimate".

Answer (score 431, accepted):

You *can* use [`:nth-last-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo); in fact, besides [`:nth-last-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-last-of-type-pseudo) I don't know what else you could use. I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic", but if you mean whether the style applies to the new second last child when more children are added to the list, yes it will. [Interactive fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/W37FU)

```
ul li:nth-last-child(2)
```

Comment: Okay that works! The code interpretator (jsfiddle) didn't validate it.. Guess a bug on their side! thanks

Comment: @David Allen: I don't think he cares if he's already trying to use `:nth-child(5)` and `:last-child`. Comments like this should either go on the question or be kept to selves.

Comment: He may not know about the no support issue.  I'm just highlighting it....  I gave a answer using jQuery and I'll happy say that it wont work with users with JavaScript disable.  but more people use IE7/8 than having JS diabled

Comment: @David, I believe the selectivrz or modernizr plugin can fix that issue, I'll have to view the docs

Comment: @ArgsKwargs Great Comment never heard of selectivizr.  Let us know if it does support nth-last-child

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can label that element with a class at the server side, you are better to use jQuery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $count = jQuery("ul li").size() - 1;
    alert($count);
    jQuery("ul li:nth-child("+$count+")").css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: It's downright annoying that jQuery doesn't implement `:nth-last-child()` just because [John thinks nobody uses it](http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use).

Comment: I'd rather label with python ;-) ontopic: Well css seems fine this way, maybe jsfiddle also thinks nobody uses it :-)

Comment: @ArgsKwargs: Strange why it wouldn't work in jsFiddle. It's up to the browser to interpret it; it doesn't have its own CSS engine.

Comment: @BoltClock don't get me wrong it does work, the code helper (color visualization) just indicates something unclosed (so I didn't even try)

Comment: I don't think any of the code is unclosed.  But i know what you mean about the "colour visualization"