# Trying to select the Semifinal div with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use CSS (3) to select the div which is not the last but one before the last. So:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="panel one"></div>
<div class="panel two"></div>
<div class="panel three"></div>
<div class="panel n"></div>
</div>
```

I always want to select the previous div before the "n" div. (number of divs varies)

I tried nth-child(n-1) but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
div.panel:nth-last-child(2)
```

from: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227932/css-last-child-1)