# CSS selector for selecting the last two children, without knowing how many items are in the list

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unordered list. It sometimes contains 4, 5, 6, or 7 items. I would like to know if there is a CSS selector to select the last two items. I realize that `:last-child` will get me the last item. Is there a "second to last child" selector? or "number of children -2" selector?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Second from Last Item</li>
  <li>Last Item</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li:last-child, ul li:last-child-1 {
  // Do something
}
```

I realize `:last-child-1` is not a selector but im hoping there is something similar out there. Any help would be greatly apprecialted.

Comment: Related: [CSS last-child(-1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227932/css-last-child-1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ul li:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
    /* .. */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Go for `:nth-last-child`

http://jsfiddle.net/pQmXM/1/

```
ul li:nth-last-child(1),
ul li:nth-last-child(2)
{
    color: red;
}
```