# reducing the last 4 containers using nth-child

Tags: css

I've got a number of products listed on my homepage, I used the nth-child element to target the last 4 to reduce the bottom margin to 0 but just doesn't seem to be working, thought it was nth-child(5), nth-child(6) etc.

live url ( http://bit.ly/1gwfpNF )

Here's a snippet

```
#layout #categories .box-1:nth-child(5) { margin-bottom: 0px; }
#layout #categories .box-1:nth-child(6) { margin-bottom: 0px; }
#layout #categories .box-1:nth-child(7) { margin-bottom: 0px; }
#layout #categories .box-1:nth-child(8) { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I learned yesterday, you may do this:

```
#layout #categories a:nth-last-of-type(-n+4) .box-1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

`nth-child` is counting inside of the parent item, so when you are looking for the `nth-child` of `.box` it will always be only one child in your case.

Comment: Thank you :) basically your answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387936/css-selector-for-selecting-the-last-two-children-without-knowing-how-many-items/22388040#22388040

Answer (score 0):

Use the !important keyword to override like this:

margin-bottom: 10px !important;

```
#layout #categories .box-1 {
width: 248px;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 10px !important;
margin-top: -140px;
margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't overuse important like that.

Comment: To overuse is another thing. I've just mentioned that it can be done this way too