# CSS select from last element up

Tags: html, css

I have a list which can have up to 5 items.

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Each list item will increment by `10%` in width. I'm using:

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 60%;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 80%;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 90%;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The last item should be `100%`

But what happens when i have less than 5 list items? If for example, there are 3 list items, the last one will be `80%`, not `100%`;

I tried using:

```
ul li:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Which makes the last item full width but the preceding ones will not respect the `10%` increment rule.

Is there any way to do something like...

```
ul li:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li:first-before-last {
  width: 90%;
}
ul li:second-before-last {
  width: 80%;
}
ul li:third-before-last {
  width: 70%;
}
```

and so on...

I am trying to achieve this with CSS only.

note: reversing everything and starting with the first at `100%` and down is not an option. The last has to be `100%` and first increment to it. It's just set up for some animations like that. I can't change it

Comment: Does each one increase by 10% or does the last item always remain 100%? or are you saying it should go from 100 and -10 each time if counting from last item?

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227932/css-last-child-1) You want to use `:nth-last-child(2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverse the logic and set the `width` starting from the last element using the `:nth-last-child` pseudoclass.

This approach requires to set as many selectors as the maximum cardinality of the list items.

```css
li:nth-last-child(n + 1) {
   width: 100%
}

li:nth-last-child(n + 2) {
   width: 90%
}

li:nth-last-child(n + 3) {
   width: 80%
}

li:nth-last-child(n + 4) {
   width: 70%
}

li:nth-last-child(n + 5) {
   width: 60%
}

li:nth-last-child(n + 6) {
   width: 50%
}



li { border: 1px #9cb solid; }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>



<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i cannot reverse

Comment: @CyberJ where you see a reverse?

Comment: @CyberJ You are just reversing the selectors in the css and nothing else

Comment: @CyberJ in your question _"Is there any way to do something like..."_ I coded exactly what you wanted.

Comment: This is a remarkably good answer. OP's actual problem is that the _last_ item should be 100%, and it should decrease in size from there.